# How do I do per-client localization in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, localization

I'm trying to do custom per-client localization in Silverlight and am running into problems.  I tried using custom cultures (en-US-c1, en-US-c2, etc), but found that doesn't work because the culture needs to exist on the client.  Is there a good clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write the user's culture to [Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/)

The values are stored as a Key/Value pair:

```
// Create an instance of IsolatedStorageSettings.
private IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings =
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

// Add a key and its value.
userSettings.Add("userCulture", "en-US-c1");

// Remove the setting.
userSettings.Remove("userCulture");
```

Just default the value to something sensible and you'll need an option to allow the user to select their culture.